# Voltages go crazy when using 74LVC8T245

Tags: integrated-circuit, buffer, texas-instruments

I am using a 74LVC8T245 buffer from Texas Instruments to interface 3.3V to 5V signals with my 3.3V microcontroller, here is my circuit:

[image: 74LVC8T245 Buffer Input]

The IC is powered by a 3.3v LDO Regulator MCP1702T. Now, when I put a 5V signal on Port B the 3.3V supply goes to 4.2-4.5V! Why is this happening? AFAIK I can go up to 5V with this IC even powering it with 3.3V.

Comment: Why is Vccb connected to 3V3?

Comment: Because on that way 3.3V signals are taken as a high level and the same for 5V signals

Comment: I don't see anything in any datasheet that states that either port is 5V-tolerant even when its supply voltage is below that.

Comment: I asked that in TI forums: http://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/etc_interface/f/391/p/204354/725453.aspx#725453

Comment: Sorry my fault I solved it. The DIR control pin was not being set to 0V apparently so B port was an Output instead of Input port. It is working correctly now! Thank you for your effort!

Comment: The response in the forum said, " For you application, the input voltage can be as high as 5.5V no matter the supply voltage in B...And can be provide 5.5V input at A side." Nothing about supplying 5 V on the B side when VCCB is 3.3 V.

Comment: @Andres, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so the question can be considered solved.

Comment: @ThePhoton The response in the forum said: "The input voltage can be as high as 5.5V no matter the supply voltage in B which is the input is 3.3V". So I can supply 5.5v powering the port with 3.3v. Really useful feature :)

Comment: @Andres You might consider the 74LVC245A as an alternative. You can power it with 3.3V and it is 5V tolerant. Fewer pins and less expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault! The DIR control pin was not being set to 0V apparently so B port was an Output instead of Input port.

This IC is 5V tolerant that means you can put 5V signals even if you are powering it with 3.3V. Read about this here: http://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/etc_interface/f/391/p/281884/987616.aspx#987616